# Why I've a cayenne connection error when I put my web site on a debian server

Tags: mysql, database-connection, apache-cayenne

I'm trying to put my web site on line. 
For that, I've a debian and a jetty server. 
When I try to go on my web site, it show my the homepage, so, this is ok.

But, when I try to log in, it put me an error message.

It's working on my local machine with this configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<domain project-version="6">
    <map name="datamap"/>

    <node name="datanode"
         factory="org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory"
        >
        <map-ref name="datamap"/>
        <data-source>
            <driver value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <url value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database"/>
            <connectionPool min="1" max="10"/>
            <login userName="username" password="password"/>
        </data-source>
    </node>
</domain>
```

So,I verified the username and password are ok. I tried to execute my web site on my own machine with the new configuration :

```
<url value="jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/database"/>
```

What did I miss?

The error message is :

[image]

(I'm sorry, I'm trying to find where I can find the jetty log on the server, I will update it with the full stack)

I supposed I forget one information? 
I'm sure about my password and login for the mysql on the server. I'm using SSH, the configuration is in my workbench :
[image]

I'm using maven, so I add mysql in the pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I read that can be because we didn't put the mysql in the classpath. But, that should works, shouldn't it?

EDIT : I tried : `<url value="jdbc:mysql://serverusername@serverpwd/serverip:3306/database"/>`, without success...

EDIT 2 : This configuration is working :

```
<node name="datanode"
    factory="org.apache.cayenne.configuration.server.XMLPoolingDataSourceFactory"
    schema-update-strategy="org.apache.cayenne.access.dbsync.CreateIfNoSchemaStrategy">
    <map-ref name="datamap" />
    <data-source>
        <driver value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <url value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/database" />
        <connectionPool min="1" max="1" />
        <autoReconnect> true</autoReconnect>
        <failOverReadOnly>  false</failOverReadOnly>
        <login userName="userName" password="password" />
    </data-source>
</node>
```

Comment: The error is a general connectivity error. Not related to your credentials. Is your database running on the same machine as your Jetty? Try to ssh to the server, and the following command there: "netstat -an |grep 3306" this will show if the DB is there and is using the expected port.

Comment: Oh ok, because I had an credential issue too ! I'll do that and give you the answer, Thanks a lot, I'm still blocking on that

Comment: The result is : tcp  0   0  127.0.0.1:3306      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN

Comment: :( no idea? I'm still block on this without any idea

Comment: Another shot in the dark. The connection may be timing out. Try adding this to the URL: "?connectTimeout=0&autoReconnect=true" . For an even more reliable result, try using an external connection pool, e.g. Hikari - http://www.baeldung.com/hikaricp with appropriate reconnect properties. Cayenne can be instructed to use an external connection pool on startup via ServerRuntime.builder(..).dataSource(dataSource)...

Comment: thanks ! I don't know why it's working now. I tried what you tell me and first it was not working. And the second time (I deployed it two times) and then it's working. I changed a little the XML file, see in the post as EDIT 2

Comment: Could you put your comment in a answer? I'll put it as solve.

Comment: I just posted the answer. Note that Cayenne will ignore <autoReconnect> and <failOverReadOnly> tags. So they don't do anything really. These parameters need to be added to the URL inside the <url value=".."/>

Comment: Ok, When I put the connect timeou and auto reconnect in the URL, I've an error like 'need a ; after autoreconnect'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection may be timing out. Try adding this to the URL: `?connectTimeout=0&autoReconnect=true`. For an even more reliable result, try using an external connection pool, e.g. [Hikari](http://baeldung.com/hikaricp), with appropriate reconnect properties. Cayenne can be instructed to use an external connection pool on startup via ServerRuntime.builder(..).dataSource(dataSource)..

Comment: Now, I don't have any issue. But, i cannot have my data stored in the database. It's a strange behavior!